# @ComponentScan takes no effect

Tags: spring

I have the following code:

Implementation of Bean:

```
package my.persist.services;
@Component
public class MyService{
}
```

Test:

```
package my.persist.services;
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={"other configuration classes", my.persist.services.MyService.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {my.persist.services.DummyPlaceHolder.class})
public class MyServiceTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
        @Autowired
        MyService service;
}
```

When I remove "**my.persist.services.MyService.class**" from `@ContextConfiguration`, the compiler says "Could not autowire, no bean of ... found", it seems the `@ComponentScan` has no effect? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than component scan for individual classes, does a wildcard scan of your base package work?

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.persist.services.*"})
```

You can exclude certain ones in your test, i.e if you want to filter out your real implementation in your test, you can do the following:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.persist.services.*"}, excludeFilters={
          @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=MyService.class)})
```